# customize the save as dialog window in autocad 2013

Tags: c#, autocad-plugin

I need to customize the save as dialog in autocad 2013 but I haven't any idea to do it.
When the user clicks on the "Save As" menu, the customized dialog should appear instead of the built-in one.
How can achieve this ?

This [link](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/manufacturing/2012/12/overriding-the-inventor-native-file-open-and-file-saveas-dialog-boxes.html)  may be usefull but I've some trouble to implement it.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to customize the SFD at the moment, I don't have a p. near me. But you could
add your own safe file dialog to the event that fires... I'm not at a computer but I believe it to be in `Autodesk.Autocad.Windows` portion of the acmgd.dll.

Comment: Thanks Trae, have you some more information about that event ?